# Plane passing through $(0,0,0)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ be a plane passing through $(0,0,0)$. Show that there is an invertible matrix $M$ such that 
$P=\left\{M\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \mid x,y \in  \mathbb{R} \right\}$.

My attempt: The equation of the plane $P$ is $ax+by+cz+d=0$. Since $P$ is passing through $(0,0,0)$, we have $0a+0b+0c+d=0$, then $d=0$. Thus $\dots$ [*incorrect here*]

Comment: Yes, that is my problem.

Comment: The set you made is a subset of $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb R^3$. It is *not* the same as $P$.

Comment: $P$ is the linear span of two independent vectors. Extend to a base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P$ is spanned by two linearly independent vectors $u_1, u_2 \in \mathbb{R}^3$. We can extend this to base $[u_1, u_2, b]$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$. $M$ is the matrix with those vectors as columns.

Comment: @Haitrung think about it. What does a product of $M$ with a vector $(x,y,0)$ look like in terms of the columns?

Comment: @Haitrung wrong there: $M\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = x\cdot u_1 + y\cdot u_2$ Left multiplication is in terms of rows.